# json array in Dart getting range error in positions higher than 0

Tags: arrays, json, flutter, dart

I am trying to get to position 1 of the array but I get a range error 0:1 in flutter dart.

I tried various ways to json.decode(data) but I keep getting the following error,

[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1

```
{
    "location": {8 items},
    "current": {23 items},
    "forecast": {
        "forecastday": [
                    {
                        "date": "2019-06-16",
                        "date_epoch": 1560643200,
                        "day": {15 items},
                        "astro": {6 items},
                        "hour": [24 items]
                    },
                    {
                        "date": "2019-06-17",
                        "date_epoch": 1560729600,
                        "day": {15 items},
                        "astro": {6 items},
                        "hour": [24 items]
                    }
                ]
        }
}
```

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';


Future<void> getData() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get('https://api.xyz'); // ( See the json copied above)

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      String data = response.body;


      var decodedData = json.decode(data);
      Map dataJ = json.decode(data);


      List fc = dataJ['forecast']['forecastday'];
      var fcc = decodedData['forecast']['forecastday'];

      print(fc[0]['date']); // works
      print(fcc[0]['date']); // works
      print(json.decode(data)['forecast']['forecastday'][0]['date']); // works

      print(fc[1]['date']); // Fails range error expects 0 got 1
      print(fcc[1]['date']); // Fails range error expects 0 got 1
      print(json.decode(data)['forecast']['forecastday'][1]['date']); // Fails range error expects 0 got 1

      // -> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1


    } else {
      print(response.statusCode);
    }
  }
```

What I expected to get was the following days date instead of an error.

Also I am able to go further through the array (still on the forecastday 0 position) It works. If I change forecastday to anything higher than 0 it fails?

```dart
print(fc[0]['hour'][4]['wind_dir']);
```

Comment: It works in all cases. Did you check the response data?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The response data is there. It does get cut short in the console though, in android studio as I am only printing the result. Not sure if that's expected behavior or not to be honest.

Comment: what happens if you `print(fcc)`? Does it show: `[Instance of Map, Instance of Map,...]`?

Comment: If I print fcc I do not get that message, I get some of the json. Starts with this. [{date: 2019-06-16, date_epoch: 1560643200 ....

Comment: If I try to get the .length of forecastday it returns 1 instead of 2. I do not know why. Does printing the result have a max char limit or file size that could be causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Issue was a days variable in the URL which was a double instead of a int. This caused the response to have current day only.